# Error formatting numpy array float values

Tags: python, numpy

```
    xtup = np.random.normal(92725500, scale=1, size=100),

    print(xtup)
    
    (array([92725499.6057292 , 92725500.93153155, 92725498.27913634, 92725498.59134175]))
    
    xtup = list(map('{:.0f}'.format,xtup))
```

When I run the above code, I get the following numpy array formatting error.

```
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to numpy.ndarray.__format__
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [274]: xtup = np.random.normal(92725500, scale=1, size=3),
     
In [275]: xtup
Out[275]: (array([92725501.65265064, 92725500.49281569, 92725498.95281461]),)
In [276]: list(map('{:.0f}'.format,xtup))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-276-cbe978a45009>", line 1, in <module>
    list(map('{:.0f}'.format,xtup))
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to numpy.ndarray.__format__
```

But if I extract the array from the tuple:

```
In [277]: list(map('{:.0f}'.format,xtup[0]))
Out[277]: ['92725502', '92725500', '92725499']
```

That format string cannot be used to format an array; it can only format numbers, such as the elements of a numeric array.

I was going to point out that the comma created a tuple, but the name `xtup` suggests you already realize that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you are getting the error, but when I run your code it works without issue.

I get this result

```
['92725500', '92725499', ..., '92725501']
```

What version of numpy are you using? That could be the issue. I am using numpy 1.19.3. If you are unsure, you can use `np.version.version` to find out.

Comment: I am on numpy version 1.19.2

Comment: Version has nothing to do with it.  He's trying to format an array within a tuple.